# Does Direct Boot mode exist for Android 8+?

Tags: android

[Direct Boot mode](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot) was added in Android 7.0. However, I cannot find if it also exists for later Android versions. The original [Google blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/04/developing-for-direct-boot.html) says "Starting with Android N", but I can't find any other sites mentioning Direct Boot mode for Android versions later than 7. Does this mode also exist for Android 8+?

Comment: it depends on the company that manufactures phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Direct Boot is available on devices where File Base Encryption is available, and since Android 10, File Base Encryption is required.

Following your original link: [Android Training Article on Direct-Boot](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot)

At the bottom there is a link to this sample Github repo: [DirectBoot](https://github.com/android/security-samples/tree/main/DirectBoot/)

Also as Direct Boot is related to encryption, another resource is the [Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/) which does have a section on [Security - File Based Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based). There you can find details about [Direct Boot](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based#direct-boot).

So to highlight the caveats as how a user or more likely a manufacturer might configure a Android 8 or 9 device with storage media:

> - **For new devices running Android 10 and higher, file-based encryption is required.**
> - **Devices running Android 9 and higher can use adoptable storage and file-based encryption.**
> - **For devices running Android 7.0–8.1, file-based encryption can't be used together with adoptable storage. If file-based encryption is enabled on these devices, new storage media (such as an SD card) must be used as traditional storage.**